# SHA1 (and whole Cryptography namespace) missing in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I copy-pasted from MSDN this code:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

byte[] buffer = enc.GetBytes(text);
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider cryptoTransformSHA1 =
            new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
string hash = BitConverter.ToString(
            cryptoTransformSHA1.ComputeHash(buffer)).Replace("-", "");

return hash;
```

but VS says there is no such `Cryptography` namespace, thus there is no `SHA1CryptoServiceProvider` class.

What am I doing wrong?

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2012 RC with Dreamspark license on Windows 8 Release Preview.

Comment: can you give the link of that code?

Comment: it's there. See MSDn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: may have not explained myself, I meant VS says he can't find that class nor namespace

Comment: Are you just missing the reference to System.Security?

Comment: just edited to remark the actual problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I take it that you are trying to create a Metro application? Metro-style applications do not support the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace. The complete list of supported .NET API namespaces for Metro applications can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230232%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**UPDATE JUNE 29**

As Guillermo has pointed out though, there is the [Windows.Security.Cryptograhy.Core](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.security.cryptography.core.aspx) namespace, that contains a [HashAlgorithmProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.security.cryptography.core.hashalgorithmprovider.aspx) class where e.g. the SHA1 algorithm can be applied.

Comment: How is that possible? Does it mean that if I want a Metro app I can't use SHA-1 anymore?

Answer (score 5):

Answer is, like Anders Gustafsson pointed, that in Metro `System.Security.Cryptography` is not supported. BUT you have `Windows.Security.Cryptography` instead.

Comment: Yes, I saw it but did not look closely enough the first time. Thanks for pointing it out. I updated my answer with some links to MSDN documentation for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `System.Security` to the references of your project.

Your error seems to be caused by this missing reference.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need a class for your code. See this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1%28v=vs.110%29

Comment: still same problem, `Cryptography` namespace is missing